# Backup of a whole encrypted Kubuntu 20.04.1 hard disk (LVMS)

Tags: partitioning, kubuntu, backup, encryption

I use Kubuntu 20.04.1 on a fully encrypted hard 500 GB disk (LVMS). I wanted to resize the partitions to make backup. Unfortunately even the latest version of partition magic is not able to resize it. I asked this question here in askubuntu in another post - but still unanswered.

As I cannot resize partitions I booted from a Live USB Stick and tired to create an image of the whole disk with GNOME Disks, but even if I unlock the encryted drive there is an error message that the disk is active or so and the backup image cannot be created. I literally cannot make any image backup of my encrypted Kubuntu. I am really suprised that there is no way to do it. Is it really not possible?

Comment: Clonezilla should be able to create an image of the whole disk. Why did you want to resize the partition to make a backup? If it was to keep the backup on the same disk it devalues it somewhat because you will be vulnerable to disk failure. If you are looking to have a way of going back to a point in time when your install was working then check out TimeShift

Comment: I have Timeshift anyway. But i am talking about creating  a full image of the disk to an external usb disk of course. Normaly you resize unencrypted Kubuntu to let's say 20 GB and backup the partitions. Here it does not work. So I tried at least to backup the 500 GB disk and not single partitions. But even this does not work because of encryption. So why does the Kubuntu team offer something what cannot be backed up?

Comment: You might want to try GParted. It has the functionality to copy paste partitions. However when dealing with an encrypted partition it has the limitation that you have to paste into an existing partition. It will not work if you try to paste into unallocated space. See the GParted manual for details. Disks may be the same or perhaps it doesn’t have functionality for encrypted partitions. Their documentation doesn’t seem to be particularly detailed.